Android emulator launched from vs code is not opening the emulator window in foreground, it is always running in background
I am experiencing an issue where the Android emulator launched from Visual Studio Code does not open in the foreground. Instead, it consistently runs in the background, making it difficult to interact with or view the emulator window.
Screenshot of background:

Then I try to click on it, to make it on foreground, but this happens:

I don't know it is happening only on Mac, it will be helpful if anyone can suggest any fix for this issue.
I am not saying that my app is not running in emulator, app is running the emulator correctly but my emulator is always hided somewhere and I am unable to keep it on desktop.


Does this answer your question? Android Emulator not launching activity to foreground

Hi @Martheen, looks like the solution you have given is something not related to my query!

The issue has been resolved by deleting and recreating the virtual devices within the Device Manager in Android Studio.
Deletion :

Recreation :


You can achieve this pretty easily by selecting the "Emulator Always on Top" option, in the hamburger (three dot) menu, of the emulator

A more detailed answer can be found here

Hi @gtxtreme, Thank you for your answer. But I am not able to click the three dot it self first of all as the emulator goes out of desktop always. It will be great if you can share how I can click that three dot menu icon

From the above image I can clearly see those controls mate

Yes I can see them, if you check the gif, whenever I clicked on emulator window it is going to background automatically because of that I am unable to click the three dot menu icon !

Try restarting your Mac once, and then try to click the three dot menu

I have restarted my Mac & uninstalled and installed the Android Emulator using Android Studio but still not working!
